# F# sequence and array2d conversion

Tags: arrays, string, f#, converters

I am creating a function to convert an Array2D of Squares to a string and then save that string to a file. Moreover I am also creating a loading function that will take in a string from a file and convert that string to an Array2D.

The Squares look like: `type Square = { x : int; y : int; number : int; optionList : int list }` and also have a few functions for creation and manipulation.

```
//Getter functions
let getNumber S = S.number
let getXpos S = S.x        
let getYpos S = S.y
let getSquareList S = S.optionList

// createSquare creates a Square at position x y
let createSquare x y = { x=x; y=y; number = 0; optionList = [1..9]}

// createSquareFromScratch creates a Square where you decide all parameters
let createSquareFromScratch x y num li = { x=x; y=y; number = num; optionList = li}

// modifiedSquare creates a Square based on an old square
let modifiedSquare x y S = { x=x; y=y; number = getNumber S; optionList = getSquareList S }
```

The part of the Squares I want to save is the number and the optionList which will result in a 10 element long string with number first and then the list. The list can be 0 to 9 elements long so if the list is shorter than 9 elements the rest can be filled with 0s. For example 5123900000 where 5 is number and 1239 is the list and 00000 is the fill.

According to my reasoning the functions should therefor somehow build a string from the array2d, maybe by using a built in higher order function or if no proper one exist in array2d then first convert to a sequence and then use a proper function from there.

The Squares are located in a 9x9 large Array2D and the order they are taken from the Array will be the order they are loaded in a later loading function (which when loading them will give them their appropriate x and y values).

How can I convert a string to an array2d of squares and array2d of squares to string?

(I have a lot of trial and error code that doesn't work but most of it is really bad and very obvious tests.) Ex:

```
let loadGame (gameAsString : string) =
    let tmp = List.ofSeq (gameAsString) |> Seq.cast<Square> |> Seq.toArray
    Array2D.init 9 9 (fun i j -> modifiedSquare i j (tmp.[((i+1)*(j+1) - 1)]))

let rec gameBoardToString (gameBoard : Square[,]) =
    match gameBoard.[0,0] with
    | x -> x.number.ToString() + x.optionList.ToString()
```

Comment: Is this a school assignment or a real project? You shouldn't, generally, invent encodings/serialization formats (unless it's an exercise), but use an existing format instead, such as JSON, XML, or YAML (my favorite is JSON). There are ready-made libraries out there that will do serialization/deserialization for you in one call each. For example: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: It's a project in which I try to learn functional f# by creating a sudoku game. The only conversion will be when I turn the game board independent on its current state to a string (to save to file) and then back again if the user want to load an old game. But I will look into json! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert array of numbers to string in the way you described, use `String.Join`:

```
let optionsToStr<'a> (opts: seq<'a>) = System.String.Join( "", opts )

> optionsToStr [0..9]
val it : string = "0123456789"
> optionsToStr [true;false]
val it : string = "TrueFalse"
```

Parsing it back, however, would be only possible if you guarantee that all numbers are within the range 0..9 - otherwise it's impossible to tell if `"12"` stands for `[1;2]` or for `[12]`. Consequently, you will probably need to come up with some kind of delimiter or another way to structure your data in text form.

Which brings me to my next point: you shouldn't, generally, invent encodings/serialization formats (unless it's an exercise), but use an existing format instead, such as JSON, XML, or YAML (my favorite is JSON). There are ready-made libraries out there that will do serialization/deserialization for you in one call each.

For example, check out [JSON.NET](http://newtonsoft.com/json):

```
let json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( gameBoard )

// Here, I assume that typeof<gameBoard> = "Square list list"
let board = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Square list list>( json )
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wondered, I will try it out! I'll also look more into JSON and the other formats. Have never used them before but will make sure to read more about them :)